# Detener notificaciones en Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.ios

Buen día.

Este es el caso:
Yo tengo una aplicación en `Xamarin.iOS` que recibe `notificaciones-push` y todo bien, lo que pasa es que en la aplicación pueden iniciar sesión varios usuarios pero puede llegar un momento en el cual el usuario elimine todas las cuentas, y por obvias razones ya no deberían de llegar notificaciones pero actualmente me llegan las notificaciones cuando ya no deberían de llegar.

mi pregunta es, ¿Cómo hacerle para detenerlas?

Comment: No he trabajado con Xamarin iOS. Depende del servicio que utilices para configurar las notificaciones push. Por lo menos en la parte de Android si usas Firebase, debes asegurarte de que hagas SignOut() al usuario actual de FirebaseAuth. Incluso hay configuraciones en el manifest de Android que te permiten limpiar los usuarios de Firebase en caso de que el  usuario desinstale la aplicacion con algun usuario actualmente logueado. Ojo, cuando digo logueado o signOut es al usuario de FirebaseAuth.

Answer (score 1):

Viéndolo desde otra perspectiva, no es dejar de recibir notificaciones en tu dispositivo iOS, sino ya no enviarle notificaciones a ese dispositivo (PlayerId).

Debes controlar desde la Aplicación que cuando un usuario cierre sesión, notificarle a tu backend (o los servicios que envían las Notificaciones Push) que ese usuario ya no está en ese dispositivo y desvincularlo para no enviarle más notificaciones.

Comment: Oh buena observación, Enrique. Lo tomaré en cuenta, gracias.